# Issues looping through the database in php

Tags: php

Am trying to loop through Database and Insert records to another table but am having error

**//Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable**

this line of code seems to be what causes the issue

```
for ($i=1; $i<=count($id); $i++) {
```

**Here is my effort so far**

```
include('pdo.php');
$result= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$result->execute(array());

while ($row = $result->fetch()){
echo $id= $row['id'];
echo $fullname = $row['fullname'];


$j=0;

for ($i=1; $i<=count($id); $i++) {
//foreach($id as $id1){ 


$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (mid,fullname) values(:mid,:fullname)');
$statement->execute(array( 
            ':mid' => $id,
                ':fullname' => $fullname,
    
));


    $j++;




}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take the count of $row (as this represents your array), you are iterating on an $id value which will throw you an error as " Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Although there is a better solution available to your problem as follows,

```
 INSERT INTO members ( 
      mid,fullname ) 
SELECT id, 
       fullname
FROM users
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using **fetchAll()** method

```
$result= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$result->execute(array());
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row)  
                        {   

$name = $row['fullname'];
$st = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (fullname) values (:fullname)');
$st->execute(array( ':fullname' => $name));


}
```